# Microsoft Outlook calendar: meeting not showing on room's calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I'm using Microsoft Outlook (version:  Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010).

I added a room to an already-existing meeting.  That worked, but the meeting doesn't appear in the room's calendar.

Just to make sure I have the room booked, I created a new meeting at the same time and booked that room.  It also doesn't show up in the room's calendar.

Is there a reason these meetings are not showing up?  (**There's plenty of other meetings that show on the room's calendar.**)

Comment: This is not a setting you can change from Outlook. You need to check with your network administrator who maintains the resource calendar on the network.

Comment: Are you saying there's a setting that would result in some meetings showing on the room's calendar **but not others**?

Comment: No. What I am saying that unless you are the administrator for the resource calendar, you will not be able to change anything from your Outlook client. There is a possibility calendar permissions have been corrupted somehow and need to be reset by the administrator. Or maybe your permission has been revoked. There is no way I can know what is causing it.

Comment: OK, thanks.  You did confirm that it's possible something's screwy, and that there's nothing I can do myself to fix it.  That's useful information.